# Get rid of TextMate2 TODO shortcut - no solution possible

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

**EDIT: There currently is no solution.** It  turns TextMate 2 doesn't maintain the ability to insert the "kill buffer" with ^Y. While it is possible to rebind a ^Y to "Paste" (command-V), I want the emacs behavior of inserting the "kill buffer".

The shortcut that inserts the "TODO" using ^y interferes with the emacs yank command. I uninstalled the TODO bundle, and couldn't find anything named "todo" or that had the shorctut ^y when I used the menu command, "Select Bundle Item...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed as of August 11, 2012.

Quoting the release notes:

> **2012-08-11**
>
> Implement ⌃Y for yanking last deletion. Nathaniel Tagg

Answer (score 1):

Maybe going into the "Keyboard" System Preferences and setting a custom keyboard shortcut for overriding that specific command in the TextMate application will solve your problem:

[image]